# How can i log only places instead of huge response data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to develop school project the project is to develop a Javascript program that takes a city and then find places and spots to visit in that city for example like a park in new york or a lake in london etc
can you please help me to do that? i am using reactjs and nodejs in my tech stack is there any way to do that?

i tried using a free api mapbox api but the API is not working when how can i do what i am trying to do?

how can I just log the places in the city to visit?

```
import axios from 'axios';

const MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'mytoken';

async function getGoodSpots(city) {
  const geocodingUrl = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${city}.json?access_token=${MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
  const geocodingResponse = await axios.get(geocodingUrl);
  const [longitude, latitude] = geocodingResponse.data.features.center;

  const placesUrl = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${longitude},${latitude}.json?access_token=${MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}&types=park,museum,restaurant`;
  const placesResponse = await axios.get(placesUrl);
  const goodSpots = placesResponse.data.features;

  return goodSpots;
}

getGoodSpots('New York City')
  .then(goodSpots => console.log(goodSpots))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

This is the huge response: how can I just log the places?

```
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: AxiosHeaders {
    'content-type': 'application/vnd.geo+json; charset=utf-8',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    date: 'Sat, 29 Apr 2023 14:27:47 GMT',
    'x-powered-by': 'Express',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'x-rate-limit-interval,x-rate-limit-limit,x-rate-limit-remaining,x-rate-limit-reset',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=604800',
    'x-rate-limit-limit': '600',
    'x-rate-limit-interval': '60',
    'x-rate-limit-reset': '1682778526',
    'last-modified': 'Thu, 27 Apr 2023 17:01:57 GMT',
    etag: '"420922bf71c38bfb0f8ce33e6e94101e"',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'x-cache': 'Hit from cloudfront',
    via: '1.1 7cf8c06084b172ee25fb1239bc5f81a0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
    'x-amz-cf-pop': 'DEL54-C1',
    'x-amz-cf-id': '3PwYExj4LnNug7AvXXeGqts2oXkaVeHkfXBOPKZiv9p5YxonrGAitw==',
    age: '4424'
  },
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.4.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/New York City.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.mapbox.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.mapbox.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 1882,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 372,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 370
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/New%20York%20City.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.4.0\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: api.mapbox.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/New%20York%20City.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: 'OK',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/New%20York%20City.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 40,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.mapbox.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/New%20York%20City.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  data: {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    query: [ 'new', 'york', 'city' ],
    features: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    attribution: 'NOTICE: © 2023 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This 
response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare.'
  }
}
::> Redis Client Connected
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 422
    at settle (file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/Backend/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/Backend/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.4.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.mapbox.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.mapbox.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 2350,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 405,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 403
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.4.0\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: api.mapbox.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 422,
      statusMessage: 'Unknown',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 38,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: true,
    host: 'api.mapbox.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 422,
    statusText: 'Unknown',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      date: 'Sat, 29 Apr 2023 15:41:31 GMT',
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'x-rate-limit-interval,x-rate-limit-limit,x-rate-limit-remaining,x-rate-limit-reset',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=604800',
      'x-rate-limit-limit': '600',
      'x-rate-limit-interval': '60',
      'x-rate-limit-reset': '1682782951',
      'last-modified': 'Thu, 27 Apr 2023 17:01:57 GMT',
      etag: 'W/"9f-pxsSaEk4gWfWlQh5G5IzSLGGgAI"',
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
      'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
      via: '1.1 7cf8c06084b172ee25fb1239bc5f81a0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
      'x-amz-cf-pop': 'DEL54-C1',
      'x-amz-cf-id': 'Il7BbnFO7aYKTM2p2UOh4BryVviVac_642sFOgGvW9LWCeTXKczMAA=='
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.4.0\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: api.mapbox.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/4.354001,50.85584.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF3ZHdhZGF3IiwiYSI6ImNsaDIya2xucTA5dGYzZm5wNmVydTUyNnEifQ.ZAOFer12TYMQfLWOKr2mwQ&types=park,museum,restaurant',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: true,
      host: 'api.mapbox.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: {
      message: 'Type "park" is not a known type. Must be one of: country, region, place, district, locality, postcode, neighborhood, address, poi, poi.landmark'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For security reasons, you should delete your current token and reissue yourself a new token.

Comment: @phatfingers i am getting just huge large response how can I just log the places?